# Textarea tag makes two rows instead of one in Firefox but works good in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, textarea

Can anyone enlightened in html explain why despite being explicitly said to make 1 row:

```
textarea id="textarea1" rows="1" cols="100"
```

the code produces two in Firefox 30:

[image]

Works in Chrome.

Comment: set this for your text area with css `#textarea1{resize:none;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox always add extra line for the textarea. 
you can use CSS to be more precise about the height length.
Or you can also try using [this css exxtension for mozilla only handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@document)